# WAMP: Fatal error: Call to undefined function ibase_connect()

Tags: windows-7, apache-http-server, php, wamp

I have a Windows 7 Pro x64 that runs the latest version of WAMP v2.4 x64, with Apache : 2.4.4 MySQL : 5.6.12 PHP : 5.4.12 PHPMyAdmin : 4.0.4 SqlBuddy : 1.3.3 XDebug : 2.2.3. When I run my code with the ibase_connect() function, I keep getting this error below:

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined function ibase_connect()
```

I've enabled the extension extension=php_interbase.dll in my php.ini without any luck. My PATH variable points to the right php bin folder, and I've tried following the instruction here http://www.alberton.info/firebird_php_windows.html, and also copying the php_interbase.dll file to my C:\Windows\system32 folder, but nothing's worked so far. Am I doing something wrong?

Please help.

Comment: Could you make a `.php` with the line `phpinfo();` and see in the result **which** `php.ini` PHP really uses (under `Loaded Configuration File`)? Did you change the `extension=php_interbase.dll` line in **that php.ini**?

Answer (score 1):

Is this any help?

[Note to Win32/Win64 Users](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ibase.installation.php)